# How do i get the sum of a column based on the user input of that particular column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

my code to calculate the sum of a column:

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
def get_additonal_data():
    import pandas as pd
    file_path = '/Users/CIS5357/Assignments/'
    data = file_path + 'grades.csv'
    df_grades = pd.read_csv(data)
    print (df_grades)
    return df_grades

def do_functions(df_grades):
    import pandas as pd
    user_input_grade = input(str("enter the grade: "))
    Print_grades =  df_grades.at[user_input_grade].sum()
    print(Print_grades)

df_grades = get_additonal_data()
do_functions(df_grades)
```

Comment: I see that you are a new contributor. Welcome to the community. Please take some time to learn about how to properly format code within a question, and how to properly structure a post. It makes everyone's lives easier, and gets you an answer quicker.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

file_path = '/Users/CIS5357/Assignments/'
data = file_path + 'grades.csv'
df_grades = pd.read_csv(data)
user_input_grade = input("enter the grade: ")
Print_grades = df_grades[user_input_grade].sum()
print(Print_grades)
```